# Flutter InappWebView canGoBack - no implementation found for method

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

I am developing navigation to the previous pages for my flutter **browser app**, and to do this I am using `goBack` and `goForward` methods of `InAppWebViewController`.

To check whether I can go back (to change color of navigation buttons) I also call `canGoBack` method. As it returns Future, I am using `FutureBuilder` to display these icons.

I propagate `canGoBack()` or `canGoForward()`  to the future field of `FutureBuilder`. And then a lot of **strange thigs** happen: sometimes when I switch between different tabs *(which work similar to tabs in https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_browser_app)*  I receive:
MissingluginException: No implementation for method canGoForward on channel com.pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_**n**, where **n** is some number

Bug usually occur when I pop back to the widget with buttons and InAppWebView from tabs page.

I've searched all related github issues and haven't found anything related, tested on android(emulator + real device), iOS (simulator + real device) - and I cannot even see the pattern of how to reproduce this bug.

So, I have several questions:

1. What may be the reasons for this to happen? At first glance, it happens at random moments
2. What 'channel' exactly means here? I would be glad to read more about that
3. May it be caused because I use FutureBuilder?